# Error code 415 while making AJAX request to server

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am sending an Ajax request to an endpoint on my server:

```java
Nothing bookSoldOut(boolean sold,
                    List<Long> books)
                        throws ErrorResponseException
```

... Where I am expecting the parameters: `sold` and `books`

In my ExtJS controller I am making a call in a function as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/book/price/bookSoldOut',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        'sold': true,
        'books': books,          
    },
    success: function(responseObject) {

    }
});
```

But I am getting an error code ***415*** - what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `books` is a composite-type *(array/object etc.)* then it's highly likely that you need to serialise the data in some way or else as a result of the object's `toString` being invoked, `[object object]` will be what is actually being sent to the server.  Typically you might use *JSON* encoded data in this case:

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/book/price/bookSoldOut',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        sold: true,
        books: Ext.encode( books )  // <-- serialise (as string)
                                    // note that some browsers will trip up
                                    // over the trailing comma you had here
    },
    success: function(responseObject) {

    }
});
```

If there is still an error after this change then something is miss-configured on the server side.